# update .po file in django without losing current translations

Tags: django

I use:

```
django-admin makemessages -l fa_IR
```

to update translation file. the process is going well without any issue. but when I run the command after translating `.po` file, all translations which have been done before will be erased and replaced with a fresh `.po` file.

the `.mo` file is still available.

Comment: They should not be erased... are you sure your `.mo` file is up to date with those translations before you run makemessages? i.e., did you run `compilemessages` first?

Comment: I compile .mo file with poedit app. should I run `compilemessages`?

Comment: Yes, try compiling the existing messages before you update to add new ones.

Answer (score 7):

Updates the message files for all available languages. Read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#makemessages) for more info

```
django-admin makemessages -a -s
```

then compile

```
django-admin compilemessages
```

and restart your server